# Information theory: Binary questions explanation

Tags: intuition, information-theory

In [Cover&Thomas](https://www.amazon.com/-/es/gp/css/order-history/?ref=hud_2_gw_profile&pf_rd_r=2DFA6EGXXXY7T8ZCB3VN&pf_rd_p=5ae85d0c-5053-4f84-84d6-e2f014761b21&pd_rd_r=5df7ae86-c83a-4cb3-82fd-dc44da6c4289&pd_rd_w=YlP5C&pd_rd_wg=CYMIM&ref_=pd_gw_unk) Example 2.1.2 there is an example of the minimum number of binary questions in order to determine the "random variable" $X$: $X=a$ with probability 1/2, $X=b$ with probability 1/4, $X=c$ with probability 1/8 and $X=d$ with probability 1/8.

One can easily see that the maximum number of questions in order to know $X$ are three questions. What I don't understand is that the text states: "The resulting expected number of binary questions required is 1.75". The entropy is precisely this number, but how to understand that three questions, out of 4 possible, is expected to be 1.75?

Comment: Why do you think the "minimum number of questions" is $3$?  Surely that's the maximum.

Comment: In any case, to solve the problem just list the three questions you plan to ask in order.  Then, what is the probability that the first settles the matter?  The second?  The third?

Comment: the questions are: Is it a? If not: is it b? If neither that: is it c? So: with probability 1/2 (a) just 1 question, with probability 1/4 (b) 2 questions, with probability 1/4 (c or d) 3 questions. The expected number of questions is1x1/2 + 2x1/4 + 3x1/4.

Comment: Perhaps they meant something else.  Obviously, it is possible to determine $X$ with a single question, though if you want to guarantee finding $X$ it takes $3$.  I wouldn't call $3$ th e"minimum number" though.

Comment: But, yes, $1\times \frac 12+2\times \frac 14+3\times \frac 14=1.75$, the expected value, as desired.  So...what is the question?

Comment: @user8268 sorry for the stupid question but, why is it not (I know it's wrong!) $1/2+1/4+1/4$?

Comment: Expected value is the probability-weighted average of the possible outcomes.   Here, it might take $1,2$ or $3$ questions to settle the point.  Thus, the answer would be $1\times p_1+2\times p_2+3\times p_3$ where $p_i$ denotes the probability that it takes exactly $i$ questions.

Comment: Duh haha, I knew I missed something! It is the average only...

Comment: To be clear, however:  it is possible to guarantee success with only two questions.  Namely:  First ask if it one of $a,b$.  If Yes, then ask if it is $a$.  If No, then ask if it is $c$.    You might try working out the expected number of questions under this strategy.

Comment: The two question strategy is "better" than than three question strategy in that the worst case takes only two questions.  However, it is "worse" in that the average number of questions it takes is also two.  To be sure "better" and "worse"  are subjective terms; and the context might determine which you actually prefer.

Comment: I don't know anything of information theory, but it appears that better means "better=lower average number of questions possible".

Comment: There can be no absolute definition of "better". Context may dictate, but it also might just be a choice.  To be sure, a particular problem might specify "optimize this for minimum mean" or "optimize this to minimize the worst case" or "optimize this to minimize variance" and so on.  Each of these, and others, can be the best answer for a particular situation.